# H2 console not loading, with error No Javascript

Tags: spring-boot, h2, h2-console

getting Error loading h2 console localhost:8080/h2-console showing following text

Welcome to H2
No Javascript
If you are not automatically redirected to the login page, then Javascript is currently disabled or your browser does not support Javascript. For this application to work, Javascript is essential. Please enable Javascript now, or use another web browser that supports it.

using spring boot with embedded database h2, I have added parameters

```
http.csrf().disable();
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by removing following line

```
 .headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self';").
```